# I have 5 letters and 10 marked envelope. In how many ways can I arrange the letters so that no letter goes in the correct envelope?

Tags: combinatorics

For each letter there is only one correct envelope.
I am trying to solve it with  **dearrangements** but am unable to reach a proper solution.

Comment: You just have to directly use the principle of inclusion exclusion. Take all the arrangements, the for each letter, subtract the arrangements where that letter is in the correct envelope, then for each pair of letters add back in the arrangements where both letters in the pair are correct, then subtract all of the triply correct arrangements, etc.

Comment: That can be done using inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_i$ denote the event that the $i$-th letter goes into the correct envelope for $i=1,2,3,4,5.$ 
Then the probability that at least one of the letters will go into the correct envelope is

> > $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{5} \Bbb P(A_i) - \sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq 5}  \Bbb P (A_i \cap A_j) +  \sum\limits_{1 \leq i<j<k \leq 5} \Bbb P (A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - \sum\limits_{1 \leq i<j<k<l \leq 5} \Bbb P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l) + \Bbb P (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5).$$

Then the required probability is the probability of the complement of the above event. So the required probability is

> > $$1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5} \Bbb P(A_i) + \sum\limits_{1 \leq i<j \leq 5}  \Bbb P (A_i \cap A_j) -  \sum\limits_{1 \leq i<j<k \leq 5} \Bbb P (A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) +\sum\limits_{1 \leq i<j<k<l \leq 5} \Bbb P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l) - \Bbb P (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5).$$

Which evaluates to

> > $$1+\frac {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5}(-1)^k \binom {5} {k} \binom {10-k} {5-k}(5-k)!} {\binom {10} {5} \cdot 5!} = \frac {9047} {15120}.$$